# ASP.NET MVC 3 with Razor engine does not seem to worked inside another project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following project structure with two MVC 3 projects with the Razor view engine  http://screencast.com/t/KzhZkgVBPg the project inside the solution folder renders an exception like this http://pastebin.com/bgHphw87

Any suggestions how to solve this or maybe another way to solve the "mounting" of the project inside another

Comment: It seems like the problem is my UIViewEngine, how do I register the AreaViewLocationFormats, AreaMasterLocationFormats and the AreaPartialViewLocationFormats to make it work with razor?

Comment: It would help if you actually explained what your UIViewEngine is doing right now. We have no way of guessing where your bug is.

Comment: Sorry for that one, my viewengine is registered in global.asax "ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new UiViewEngine());" and is pretty simple like this http://pastebin.com/7GdEZDbF

Answer (score 0):

Usually your views go in the ~/Views folder, which has a web.config that contains the following:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="ClassLibrary1.MyBasePage">
        ...
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

This sets the base type used when Razor compiles the views. Based on your screenshot, it looks like your files are outside of the ~/Views folder, and therefore the pageBaseType might not be set. Try putting a Web.config (like the one in your ~/Views folder) in your UI folder (or subfolder).

Comment: By the way - I'm curious as to the strange project structure. Why store the files inside the web app, but then create another project to edit them?